# using checkboxes in html and nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, db2

I am trying to basically allow users to select sizes that they are going to have for their product, and I have used checkboxes. So the options are XS, s, m, l, xl. Whichever of the options the user selects, I need it to upload those to the database where it stores the sizes of that specific product. I would like to only upload the sizes that the user has selected to the database, so that it doesn't show up as an undefined size in the db.

FRONT-END

```
<label for="productCategory">SIZES (OPTIONAL):</label>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="(EX) XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL" style="border: 1px solid black"> -->
    <label for="check-1">Extra Small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xs" id="extra-small" value="xs">
    <label for="check-1">Small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="s" id="small" value="small">
    <label for="check-1">Medium</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="m" id="medium" value="medium">
    <label for="check-1">Large</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="l" id="large" value="large">
    <label for="check-1">Extra Large</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xl" id="extra-large" value="xl">
```

BACKEND (NODEJS)

```
    var xs = req.query.xs
    var s = req.query.s
    var m = req.query.m
    var l = req.query.l
    var xl = req.query.xl
        var addProducts = "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZE, COLOURS, IMAGE ) VALUES ('" + req.query.item + "', '" + req.query.description + "', '" + req.query.price + "', '" + size + "', '" + req.query.colours + "', '" + image_url + "' )"
```

I am having a little bit of a brain fart and cannot figure this out for some reason, lol. thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who will look at this question, I figured it out.

Basically you need to set the value of each  on the front end to ex. `size[]`, and then on the backend, `var size = req.query.size` and then perform the insert query into the db.